# Aligning content from center to sides in CSS

Tags: css, alignment, centering

is it possible to center buttons like on image below? The problem is that natural align center is aligning depending on the width of content, in my case I need to center from the Button 2 center to sides, and in other case from the middle of  to sides. Can this be achieved with CSS only?

I tried using flex, but it seems there should be a different solution.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

[JSFiddle example with test cases](https://jsfiddle.net/no1lov3sme/yf9hgxu1/14/)

[image]

Comment: if you know the width of each element, you can still align them with position absolute

Comment: Width is unknown, I know it is possible to be done using JS, but I hope there is an option to do this with CSS only.